# Filters and intersection of two binary relations

Tags: filters, gn.general-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, tag-removed

Let $\mathfrak{F}$ is the complete lattice of filters (including the improper filter) on some set, ordered
inverse to set-theoretic inclusion.

I will denote $\left\langle f \right\rangle \mathcal{X} = \bigcap^{\mathfrak{F}} \left\{ f \left[ X \right] | X \in \mathcal{X} \right\}$ for every binary relation $f$ and filter $\mathcal{X}$.

Let $\forall \mathcal{X}\in\mathfrak{F}:\left( \mathcal{X} \cap^{\mathfrak{F}} \mathcal{A} \neq 0^{\mathfrak{F}}
\Rightarrow \left( \left\langle f \right\rangle \mathcal{X}
\supseteq^{\mathfrak{F}} \mathcal{B} \wedge \left\langle g \right\rangle
\mathcal{X} \supseteq^{\mathfrak{F}} \mathcal{B} \right) \right)$ for some binary
relations $f$ and $g$ and filters $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$.
($0^{\mathfrak{F}}$ is the filter which is the least in our order that is the
biggest in set-theoretic order.)

Does the implication $\forall \mathcal{X}\in\mathfrak{F}:\left( \mathcal{X} \cap^{\mathfrak{F}} \mathcal{A} \neq
0^{\mathfrak{F}} \Rightarrow \left\langle f \cap g \right\rangle
\mathcal{X} \supseteq^{\mathfrak{F}} \mathcal{B} \right)$ follow from the
above assumption?

You can read http://www.mathematics21.org/algebraic-general-topology.html for
my related research.

Comment: I honestly do not know what your formulas mean...

Comment: (For example: is "the filter which is the least in our order that is the biggest in set-theoretic order" a circumlocution for "the filter of all sets"?)


Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: Yes, this is the filter of all sets. Also $f[X] = \{ y | \exists x\in X: (x;y) \in f \}$.

Comment: And I guess «$\bigcap^{\mathfrak F}$» is exactly the same thing as $\bigcap$...

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: What else do you not understand?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Alvarez: $\bigcap^{\mathfrak F}$ is the infimum on the lattice $\mathfrak{F}$ (= supremum on the lattice of filters ordered by set-theoretic inclusion)

Comment: The condiction: $ \mathcal{X} \cap \mathcal{A} \neq 0^{\mathfrak{F}} $  i true if and only if $ \mathcal{X}$ or  $\mathcal{A}$ dont coicide by  the all sets filter $0^{\mathfrak{F}}$.

Comment: Who receives the bounty if the asker has already accepted his own answer?

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1622

Comment: Your bounty request follows as in this answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31747/union-of-uniformly-connected-sets/135057#135057

Answer (score 6):

No; non-Hausdorff ultrafilters give a counterexample.  In detail, let $\mathcal B$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on an infinite set $N$.  Let $M=\{(x,y)\in N\times N:x\neq y\}$.  Let $f$ and $g$ be the two projection functions from $M$ to $N$.  Let $\mathcal A$ be any ultrafilter on $M$ containing all the sets $f^{-1}(X)$ and $g^{-1}(X)$ for $X\in\mathcal B$.  I claim that $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ satisfy the hypothesis in your question.  Indeed, if $\mathcal X$ is coherent with $\mathcal A$, then it is a subset of (i.e., higher in your ordering than) $\mathcal A$ because the latter is an ultrafilter.  Therefore, the images of $\mathcal X$ under $f$ and under $g$ are subsets of the images of $\mathcal A$, both of which are $\mathcal B$.  On the other hand, I also claim that your proposed conclusion fails.  Indeed, $f\cap g$ is the empty relation (because the diagonal of $N\times N$ was removed in the definition of $M$), and therefore the image of any filter under $f\cap g$ is the improper filter, which is not a subset of $\mathcal B$.

Comment: What are projection functions from $M$ to $N$? I understand what is a projection function from $N\times N$ to $N$, but don't understand what is a projection function from $M$ to $N$.

Comment: @porton: Restrict the projections to have domain $M$.

Comment: I don't understand why images of $\mathcal{A}$ under $f$ and $g$ are $\mathcal{B}$. Is $X$ a fixed arbitrary element of $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: That the images of $\mathcal A$ under $f$ and $g$ are both $\mathcal B$ is immediate from the definition of images and of $\mathcal A$.  In the latter definition, $X$ ranges over all $X\in\mathcal B$.  In excessive but perhaps necessary detail: Since $f$ is a function and $\mathcal A$ is an ultrafilter, $f(\mathcal A)$ is an ultrafilter.  If $X$ is any set in $\mathcal B$, then `$f^{-1}(X)$` is in $\mathcal A$, so `$f(f^{-1}(X))\in f(\mathcal A)$`.  But `$f(f^{-1}(X))$` is a subset of $X$, so $X\in f(\mathcal A)$.  (continued in next comment)

Comment: That shows $\mathcal B\subseteq f(\mathcal A)$; since both of these are ultrafilters, they are equal.